# How Can I Remove a Property From a Protobuf?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, protocol-buffers

I want to remove a property from an instantiated entity_pb.EntityProto, instantiated in this way:

```
pb = entity_pb.EntityProto()
prop1 = pb.add_property()
prop1.set_name('prop1')
prop2 = pb.add_property()
prop2.set_name('prop2')
```

Suppose I don't want prop1 any more. How can I remove it?

This question relates to wanting to inject protobufs into an AppEngine datastore, but existing protobufs with the `__scatter__` property cannot be put.  If I try to put the entity, it comes back with this error: `BadRequestError: cannot store entity with reserved property name '__scatter__'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the result of `pb.property_list()`, so this would work:

```
 properties = pb.property_list()
 properties[:] = [e for e in properties if e.name() != '__scatter__']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [protobuf documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview), there's not anything on manipulating individual EntityProtos.  The code within entity_pb.py doesn't show any related methods either, so I went with the "let's manipulate the object directly even though you're not really supposed to" approach.

```
props = element.property_
for i in range(len(props)):
    if props[i].name() == '__scatter__':
        props.pop(i)
        break
```